# Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds in CURL and PHP Geocoder

Tags: php, curl

I have a script with a loop in which I execute the PHP geocoder function.
The loop has more than 1000 iterations and the whole process takes some time.
This is my script:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < 1000; $x++) { 

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// GECODE THE ADRESS AND GET THE COORDS
$curl     = new \Ivory\HttpAdapter\CurlHttpAdapter();

$geocoder = new \Geocoder\Provider\BingMaps($curl,$bingApikey);
//$geocoder = new \Geocoder\Provider\MapQuest($curl,$mapQuestApikey);
//$geocoder = new \Geocoder\Provider\ArcGISOnline($curl);
//$geocoder = new \Geocoder\Provider\OpenStreetMap($curl);


$result =  $geocoder->geocode($matchesAdressRightValues[$x][0]);

if (count($result)==0 || count($result)>1 ){
    $bingSucUn = 'not_success'; 
    array_push($arraySucUnsucBing,$bingSucUn);
}   
else {
    //echo ('result');
    //echo (count($result));
    //echo ('Endresult');
    $bingSucUn = 'success'; 
    array_push($arraySucUnsucBing,$bingSucUn);
}
//var_dump($result);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}  // end for
```

The problem is I get an error:

```
(&quot;Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds&quot;).
```

How can I increase the limit?
I have added this on top of my screen but its only for PHP not for the curl request:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Normally if I was using pure CURL and not integrated in the PHP Geocoder then I would do something like that:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1000);
```

But what should I do now?

Comment: Nope. Not a duplicate. This question is focusing in the use of CURL within the PHP Geocoder.

Comment: Ah ok after I read your comment I googled what geocoder is in detail. Maybe this `CurlHttpAdapte` may help: https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder/pull/284/files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar error, and this was due to the proxy settings. I have set my proxy by:

```
Sys.setenv(https_proxy="http://proxy:8000")
```

Later I was able to download.

Answer (score 5):

### Disclaimer

I built this by reading the docs, I don't have the package installed and couldn't test it.

### Setting the timeout in ivory-http-adapter

The official way, from the docs:

> > $configuration->setTimeout(30);
>
> https://github.com/egeloen/ivory-http-adapter/blob/master/doc/configuration.md

### The code

```
// new curl
$curl = new \Ivory\HttpAdapter\CurlHttpAdapter();

// get curl config
$conf = $curl->getConfiguration();

// set timeout
$conf->setTimeout(30);

// save config
$curl->setConfiguration($conf);
```

Short version

```
// curl + timeout (quick version)
$curl = new \Ivory\HttpAdapter\CurlHttpAdapter();
$curl->setConfiguration($curl->getConfiguration()->setTimeout(30));
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a more proper way than what I did.

Comment: I'm the maintainer of the ivory http adapter library and the short answer is: ``$curl->getConfiguration()->setTimeout(30);``

Answer (score 2):

I managed to change the CURL TIMEOUT option by finding the php file which contains the CurlHttpAdapter. The path for this file (in the GEOCODER PHP installation) was:

```
vendor\egeloen\http-adapter\src
```

I commented these two lines:

```
//$this->configureTimeout($curl, 'CURLOPT_TIMEOUT');
//$this->configureTimeout($curl, 'CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT');
```

and added this line:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,0);
```

That solved this problem..

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to do a heavy task (or a lot of light tasks). It's better to do this in an asynchronous call out of the web request, **calling your script directly from the operating system**. Also this task can fail due to external problems, you need connection to the geocoder service.

I would run this from a **[cron task](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)** and **log the results to a database** shared with the web application. This way the app can check how went the task execution and get the results. Note that this task can fail, and the problem is not **the timeout**, *(that is just the problem's messenger!)* the timeout tells you that something went wrong, and you need to find this something in other place: the server network connection, your hosting, the host you are requesting, the library you are using, etc.

So you have to take a different approach. Good luck!